# Async Batch Google Vision Text detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-vision

i'm trying to use google vision to detect text from a batch of 15 documents at once, i want it to be don't Asynchronously.

unfortunately the time it takes for client.async_batch_annotate_images() function, is the same as client.batch_annotate_images() function, which is the same time it takes if i iterate over the list of features with client.document_text_detection()

i am not sure why the response takes so much time, and maybe i am doing something wrong, i would love to get your expert opinion on this.

for example, that is how i extract the text using batch annotate images

```
        def batch_ocr_images():

            client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

            requests = []
            features = [vision.Feature(type_=vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)]
            for image_file in images_files:
                with io.open(image_file, 'rb') as image_data:
                    content = image_data.read()

                image = vision.Image(content=content)
                request = vision.AnnotateImageRequest(image=image, features=features)
                requests.append(request)


            client.batch_annotate_images(requests=requests)
```

is this how it should work asynchronously? because it works the same speed as it does when i iterate over the images and scan one image at a time.

thanks in advance,
Yaniv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed is expected to be the same as the speed configuration is on the back-end of Google. There’s no option to speed up on user/developer's end.
The only difference between asynchronous and synchronous is you can do requests even offline when you are using asynchronous and you can specify larger batches of files compared to using synchronous. To read more about batch image annotation you may refer to this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch).

Comment: is there a way to speed up my requests?
because sometimes i have 50 documents i want to OCR, and waiting for over 60 seconds for it is too much..
i tried using threads, but for some reason the google client blocks me.

Comment: @YanivAkiva, edited my answer. Just to manage the expectation, as advised, speed configuration is on the backend of Google. There is no tool available for the purpose of speeding up on developer's end.